# Не приходит СМС двухфакторной аутентификации VK.net c#

Tags: c#, wpf, vkontakte-api, vknet

Есть метод, который обрабатывает аутентификацию:

```
        private void VKLogin(string Login, string Password)
    {
        try
        {
            MainWindow.vk.Auth(Login, Password);
            mainWindow.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MainWindow.vk.vkApi.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
            {
                Login = Login,
                Password = Password,
                ApplicationId = AppID,
                TwoFactorAuthorization = TheSecondAuth
            });
        }
    }
    private string TheSecondAuth()
    {
        string result = "";

        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            TwoFactorAuth dlg = new TwoFactorAuth();

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                result = dlg.TwoFactorCode;
            }
        });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.IsBackground = true;

        t.Start();
        t.Join();

        return result;
    }
```

Код из TwoFactorAuth:

```
        public string TwoFactorCode = "";
    public TwoFactorAuth()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TwoFactorCode = TwoFactorCodeTextBox.Text;
        if (TwoFactorCode != "")
        {
            DialogResult = true;
        } 
    }
```

В итоге такой аутентификации не приходит код, окно с вводом открывается, если ввести туда любой код, то пожалуется, что код не правильный, но, как я уже писал, самого кода он не отправляет, а в гайде, где я смотрел всё работало правильно.

Попробовал реализовать так же, как и указано в документации:

```
                MainWindow.vk.vkApi.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
            {
                Login = Login,
                Password = Password,
                ApplicationId = AppID,
                TwoFactorAuthorization = () =>
                {
                    ConsoleController.ShowConsole();
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите код: ");
                    return Console.ReadLine();
                }
            });
            ConsoleController.CloseConsole();
```

Но оно тоже не сработало, я ещё заметил то, что при входе на аккаунт через браузер, то код приходит звонком, а не смс, но в любом случае должно же как-то заработать.

Comment: Жмете F11 и шаг за шагом проходитесь по своему коду, и смотрите, как и когда выполняется нужный кусок кода. Сейчас у вас каша, намешали все в одну кучу, и статику, и потоки, диалоги, и прочее. Вот зачем вам статика? `MainWindow.vk` явно ведь vk статичен... А `Thread` зачем? В наше время, так напрямую использовать потоки нужно лишь в очень крайних ситуациях, ибо есть `async`.

Comment: Я не спрашивал о том, что у меня не такой красивый код и т.д., у меня есть проблема, указанная в теме, которая Вашим ответом не была решена.

Comment: Негатив поубавьте, я вам не давал еще каких-либо ответов, я лишь **комментирую** то, что вижу. Вместо того, чтоб негативно реагировать, лучше бы намотали бы на ус, подумали бы, "и правда, а почему я это все тут так написал, может так не стоит?". К тому же, подобный код может быть причиной проблем, например у вас из-за потока может быть несинхронное выполнение, когда вы например спрашиваете код, который еще даже не запросили, поэтому я вам и сказал, запустите проект под отладкой и шаг за шагом посмотрите, как и когда выполняется.

Comment: Ну а чтоб убедиться, что проблема не в библиотеки, сделайте консольный проект, скопировав в него прям код из документации библиотеки, и посмотрите, приходит там код подтверждения или нет. Если нет, и как вы говорите "приходит звонком", то может этот функционал не реализован в библиотеки? Может тогда стоит поговорить с авторами на их GitHub? Ну это так, догадки...

Comment: Несколько минут данный код работал, т.е. приходило смс, но спустя небольшое количество времени опять перестало приходить, скорее всего проблема в VkNet.

Comment: Тогда стоит обратиться на GitHub и задать этот вопрос автору библиотеки.

Comment: При использовании инструкции из GitHub в пустом консольном проекте аналогично не работает.